# Windows environment variable in Java build path

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

How do I use a Windows environment variable to specify where a jar is located in an Eclipse project build path?

The JAVA_HOME environment variable for example could be in a different location on the server than on my PC, but if I have JAVA_HOME set as an environment variable on both machines, how can I specify in Eclipse to use a jar in the JAVA_HOME so it is the same on both machines?

Comment: I'm not certain that you can; there are "Classpath Variables" under "Preferences -> Java -> Build Path" but they don't use the "Windows" environment. If you have the jar in your workspace you can just right click on it, and select "Build Path -> Add to Build Path".

Answer (score 1):

If your using Maven, just put an entry in your pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>com.mysite</artifactId>
    <groupId>mylib</groupId>
    <version>${mylib.version}</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mylib-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This requires you install the Maven M2E plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks but what is Maven

Comment: Maven is build tool that helps you organize your source code directories, build process, and classpath management.  See:  http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html  .  Using it requires that you "convert" your project into a Maven project in Eclipse.  If it's too complex, there is also a build tool called Gradle that you can use that works similarly.